# Entity Framework column-entity correlation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm really new in EF, and I'm suddenyl stuck with a problem:

```
        var _entity = new TestEntity();

        _entity.Customers.Add(new Customers { Description = "John" });
        _entity.Customers.Add(new Customers { Customer_ID = 1, Description = "Steve" });

        try
        {
            _entity.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)
        {
            Debug.Print("Validation Error");
        }
```

After running this code, I've got a result which insterted two records without any exception, but my problem is that Customer_ID field does not allow null or define any default value. However, "John"-record has inserted with Customer_ID: 0.
(And of course, "Steve"-record also, with the correct ID: 1)

How can I manage to throw an expection, or at least validate more deeply before inserting values, and if not defined by code, keep away from inserting?

The model class is here:

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)] 
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] 
    public int Customer_ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)] 
    [StringLength(50)] 
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for int is 0 which is not null and you were able to insert it to DB. If you want to check if Customer_ID is assigned to larger value than 0 you can try `Range` attribute.

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)] 
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] 
[Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be larger than 0.")]
public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
```

Another ugly solution might be marking changing the property type to `int?` and applying the `Required` attribute like this:

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)] 
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] 
[Required]
public int? Customer_ID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it.

So I should sign the value as nullable:

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)] 
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] 
public int? Customer_ID { get; set; }
```

And in this case, I've just got a DbUpdateException. Maybe a solution, but maybe not the best, so other suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

On the database side, I highly recommend putting a CHECK constraint on Customer_ID so that it doesn't allow 0. This will prevent mistakes in your application from leaking into the database.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear if you want for Customer_ID to accept null or not?
public int Customer_ID { get; set; } has the default value of 0 so what you get is correct.

if is needed try:

```
[Required]
public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
```

if it can be null

```
public int? Customer_ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Okay, in the table definition from SQL side, Customer_ID is not allows null. In my code, I don't define the value for John-record, so it means - from my point of view - I don't give a value for Customer_ID, so it should be null by default, and get an exception, that watch out, you don't define value for ID.

Comment: Well in C# you have a property Customer_ID of type int and this means that the default value of Customer_ID is 0. So in other words if you want in db to see NULL you have to have a nullable type as propery ex: public int? Customer_ID { get; set; } . And then the new rows will have null.

Comment: You have to add a new row after this to see it working.

Comment: @user1692315 Let me put it this way, if you debug when you create a new object you will see that Customer_ID  is 0 . So that 0 in db is from here.

Comment: If you can, drop the table and create it again. The EF can not convert int to nullable<int> . So if you can, go back from the begin.